# Is gerrit able to handle interdependent commit between different repos?

Tags: gerrit

I have a project which includes two repos, let's say their status are version1@repo1, version1@repo2

Now I have to commit two changes to those two repos to make history become version2@repo1 and version2@repo2.

Only version2@repo1 + version2@repo2 can be built correctly, so those two commits are interdependent and they must be merged same time.

Is gerrit able to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Gerrit supports that use case. Changes can be grouped via `topic`: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#topics

But building must be done on your own in your build scripts.